# Take the mean of multi torch.Tensor list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

The project needs to iterate over the data multiple times and then average it

```
gradslist = []
for data_epoch in interval_steps:
    output = cnn.forward(b_x)[0] 
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(output, b_y)
    cnn.zero_grad()  
    loss.backward()    
    w_c1 = cnn.conv1[0].weight.grad
    b_c1 = cnn.conv1[0].bias.grad
    w_c2 = cnn.conv2[0].weight.grad
    b_c2 = cnn.conv2[0].bias.grad
    w_o = cnn.out.weight.grad
    b_o = cnn.out.bias.grad       
    grads = [w_c1,b_c1,w_c2,b_c2,w_o,b_o]
    gradslist.append(grads)
```

```
w_c1 type= torch.Tensor  shape=  torch.Size([64, 1, 5, 5])  
b_c1 type= torch.Tensor  shape=  torch.Size([64])  
w_c2 type= torch.Tensor  shape=  torch.Size([144, 64, 5, 5])  
b_c2 type= torch.Tensor  shape=  torch.Size([144])  
w_o type= torch.Tensor  shape=  torch.Size([10, 2304])  
b_o type= torch.Tensor  shape=  torch.Size([10])
```

I want the average

```
avggrads = [avg_w_c1, avg_b_c1, avg_w_c2, avg_b_c2, avg_w_o, avg_w_0]
```

The result of avggrads is not a list of values, but a torch.tensor list, such as avg_w_c1.shape= torch.size ([64, 1, 5, 5]), not a value. it is the average of the `corresponding position (Matrix averaging)`

Please advise how to average multiple grads in gradslist.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```
avggrads = [sum(grads)/len(gradslist) for grads in zip(*gradslist)]
```

**Explanation:** `zip(*gradslist)` will group the corresponding elements together from each list inside `gradslist`, so in your case, it will return 6 tuples: one with all the gradient of `w_c1` and one for all the gradients of `b_c1` and so on. Then `sum(grads)/len(gradslist)` will compute the average for each tuple.